# Is there any way to retrieve a web card code?

Tags: skylanders-cloud-patrol

In Skylanders: Cloud Patrol, the game allows you to unlock owned Skylanders by using the web card code that came with them. Unfortunately, I didn't think to keep the cards and have either thrown them away or misplaced them. Is there any way to retrieve the codes that were on the cards so that I can input them into Cloud Patrol?

Comment: I don't think these codes are unique to your figures, they're just like serial codes generated to each copy of the game. I don't think you'd be able to get them "off the figurine".

Comment: the code for flameslinger is LFYQT-X7M4D

Comment: So far all it does is tell me I have an invalid code. I've tried 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with at least the 1.6 version of Skylanders: Cloud Patrol, they detail in the Get Help section on how to retrieve your Web Card Code (image below).  [image: Get Help Section]

In summary, to retrieve your code, you need to have a [Skylanders Spyro's Universe](http://universe.skylanders.com) account, with your characters imported into your game (from the portal if you lost your code). After logging in to the game, you can tap on the My Info button, and see the Web Card Code for each character you have imported into the game. You can then use that Web Card Code within Skylanders: Cloud Patrol.

[image: Screenshot of My Info]

Comment: For future reference, since May 2013 this option is no longer available, since the Skylanders Universe website was shut down.

Answer (score 1):

Although you can't retrieve the cards, you have two options. One is when you play on the console version, press select to see the current Skylander's stats. You can scroll all the way over to the right and see an option that says webcode which will give you a code to use on Skylander's Online.

Another option is to plug the Portal of Power into your USB port and download the driver from the Skylander Online website to use the Portal for the Online game. Although I haven't tried this way, all you have to do is drop the skylander on the portal of power to add it to the online game. Hope this helps.

Comment: Is this relevant to the Cloud Patrol game?

Comment: The Web code that can be retrieved from a Skylanders stats is not the same as the one on the web card code. When used inside Cloud Patrol, the 'Web Code' is one character short, and doesn't match a web card code (I have one I found to check against).